# Заполнение RecyclerView элементов из JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

**Что делаю:**
Я получаю все JSONObjects с моего сервера через websockets в `MainActivity` и кладу их в `ArrayList<JSONObject>`:

```
 usersInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = contacts.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("id", contacts.get(i));
            socket.emit("info", obj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.off();
        socket.on("user_info", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                userInfo = (JSONObject) args[0];
                usersInfo.add(userInfo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

К этой активити у меня прицеплен Fragment и чтобы передать ему данные я использую в этой активности этот метод:

```
public static ArrayList<JSONObject> getUsersInfo(){return usersInfo;}
```

Далее уже в фрагменте я получаю данные с помощью этого метода:

```
usersInfo = MainActivity.getUsersInfo();
```

И начинаю распарсивать его и вставлять все в элементы RecyclerView:

```
 for (int i = usersInfo.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        try {
            adapter.editItemByID(usersInfo.get(i).getString("id"), usersInfo.get(i).getString("status"), "online");
            adapter.editItemByID(usersInfo.get(i).getString("id"), usersInfo.get(i).getString("nick"), "nick");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Просмотрев в Debug режиме, что данные **успешно** передаются, удостоверяюсь что все данные будут успешно распарсены и вставлены в элементы!. НО! При запуске приложения эти элементы не обновились и остались null, как я их задал по умолчанию. Но при обновлении фрагмента (нажал на BottomNavigationView) Эти данные берут и появляются.

Мне максимально не понятна эта ошибка, так как в DebugMode все данные успешно переправляются между классами.

---

У меня два вопроса.

1. Как это исправить и в чем заключается ошибка
2. Правильно ли передавать данные между классами вот таким способом?

   public static ArrayList getUsersInfo(){return usersInfo;}
   usersInfo = MainActivity.getUsersInfo();

**Дополнение:(без холдера RecyclerView)**

```
public class DialogsFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private Socket socket = AuthActivity.socket;
private JSONObject userInfo;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialogs, null);
    RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogs);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    ArrayList<String> chats = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<DialogInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> contacts = MainActivity.getContacts();
    ArrayList<MessagesObject> messages = MainActivity.getMessages();
    String id = MainActivity.getUserAuthID();

    for(int i = contacts.size()-1; i>=0; i-- ){
        data.add(new DialogInfo("null", contacts.get(i), "null", "null", contacts.get(i), "false"));
    }



    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.addAll(data);

    for (MessagesObject message : messages) {
            if (id.equals(message.getSenderId()) && !search(chats, message.getRecipient())) {
                chats.add(chats.size(), message.getRecipient());

                adapter.editItemByID(message.getRecipient(), "Вы: "+message.getMessage(), "lm");

            } else if (!id.equals(message.getSenderId()) && !search(chats, message.getSenderId())) {
                chats.add(chats.size(), message.getSenderId());

                adapter.editItemByID(message.getSenderId(), message.getMessage(), "lm");

            } else if (id.equals(message.getSenderId())) {

                adapter.editItemByID(message.getRecipient(), "Вы: "+message.getMessage(), "lm");

            } else {

                adapter.editItemByID(message.getSenderId(), message.getMessage(), "lm");

            }
    }
    for (int i = contacts.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("id", contacts.get(i));
            socket.emit("info", obj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.off();
        socket.on("user_info", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                userInfo = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    adapter.editItemByID(userInfo.getString("id"), userInfo.getString("status"), "online");
                    adapter.editItemByID(userInfo.getString("id"), userInfo.getString("nick"), "nick");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}


private boolean search(ArrayList<String> chats, String recipient){

    for(int i =0; i<chats.size(); i++){
        if(chats.get(i).equals(recipient)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<DialogInfo> items = new ArrayList<>();

    void addAll(List<DialogInfo> fakeItems) {
        int pos = getItemCount();
        this.items.addAll(fakeItems);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, this.items.size());
    }

    void editItemByID(String id, String editValue, String editItem){
        for(int position = 0; position < items.size(); position++){
            if(items.get(position).getId().equals(id)){
                switch (editItem) {
                    case "nick":
                        items.get(position).setName(editValue);
                        break;
                    case "lm":
                        items.get(position).setLastMessage(editValue);
                        break;
                    case "time":
                        items.get(position).setTime(editValue);
                        break;
                    case "photo":
                        items.get(position).setPhoto(editValue);
                        break;
                    case "id":
                        items.get(position).setId(editValue);
                        break;
                    case "online":
                        items.get(position).setOnline(editValue);
                        break;
                }


                notifyItemChanged(position);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

в Фрагменте

```
userInfo=new ArrayList<>();
usersInfo = MainActivity.getUsersInfo();
```

Comment: и что? Можно немного более описанный ответ?

Comment: вы инициализировали userInfo в вашем Фрагменте до этого присваивания ?usersInfo = MainActivity.getUsersInfo();

Comment: Конечно, как я и говорил в вопросе в Debug режиме данные в эту коллекцию успешно записываются. Но вот логи говорят, что он пустой. Как такое может быть?

Comment: Можно посмотреть код Фрагмента?

Comment: Конечно, вернусь домой и дополню вопрос

Comment: хорошо. посмотрю и скажу вам

Comment: Все обновил, можете смотреть

Comment: как я понял ошибка выдает на этих строках так?
ArrayList<String> contacts = MainActivity.getContacts();
    ArrayList<MessagesObject> messages = MainActivity.getMessages();

Comment: data заполняется нулевыми объектами,  я же в начале говорил)
нужно сперва создать объект, а потом  уж присвоить к нему что то.
т.е.
ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
contacts=MainActivity.getContacts();
    ArrayList<MessagesObject> messages = new ArrayList<>();
messages=MainActivity.getMessages();

Comment: Упс, я скинул код без кода с ошибкой.  То чтт здесь все работает . Сейчас обновлю

Comment: хорошо, добавьте, жду